# mongo - better solution when i have to update each mongo document usually?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let say, If i have a document like this, and this collection have huge documents.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('e1312313dddqqe….'),
  ra: {
    energy: 80,
    times: 1377496519
  }
}
```

i have to update ra.energy usually (per 15 mins), use this formula

```
var pow = (now - ra.times) / 86400;
ra.energy = ra.energy * ( Math.pow(0.5, pow) );
```

Currently, we use cronjob, query each documents, do the calculate and update back to each ra.energy field, but it will slow down our MongoDB.

Is there have any better design to do this update. any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Be slow to call it "stupid" until you understand how it can be done in a better way. Even then, just because you found a smarter way, doesn't necessarily mean the old way was "stupid".

Comment: The energy seems to depend only on the time-field and the current time, so is there a reason to not just query for the time-field and calculate the energy on the application layer?